# Nullable enum in html helper

Tags: c#, html-helper, nullable

I have a view model that contains enum with nullable type like this one :

```
public StudyLevel? studyLevel { get; set; }
```

I have made custom html helper to display a dropdownlist for rendering the enum into the view, the nullable case is displayed using

```
<option value="null">No value</option>
```

the problem is that when i submit the form modelstate give me the error :

```
studylevel cannot be "null" .
```

Could you suggest me any way to help me handle the nullable type in the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change your html helper to display the null value like this?

```
<option>No value</option>
```

Or like this?

```
<option value="">No value</option>
```

Edit: A better option (IMO) is to create a collection of `SelectListItem` and then use a built-in HTML helper. Please take a look into this article I created some months ago, it may help you. You can use it like this:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownList<StudyLevel?>("studyLevel", "No value")
```

More info here:

[ASP.NET MVC: Creating localized DropDownLists for enums](http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/asp-net-mvc-creating-localized-dropdownlists-for-enums/)

Comment: curiously it bind my view model correctly with null value but the model state give me the errors : The value 'No value' is not valid for studyLevel .

Comment: However i am using jquery to submit my form so i think i will juste remove the option with no value from the serialisation

Comment: @FabienPiron: I just  edited my answer and included an alternative solution to your problem

Comment: finaly the solution was to display option value="" , thanks any way for the help ;)

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but I am pretty sure there are some limitations around nullable enums and the MVC default model binder. I would recommend having a state which represents "*no value*" instead e.g.

```
StudyLevel.None
```

That way you don't need to deal with checking for `null` etc.